# Updating only those fields which users have changed in a Form

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a form that contains 16 to 20 fields including input type texts and textareas.

The form submits the fields using POST method to a php page which updates a table in a
database with the $_POST vars.

My Question is that I want to update the changed values only in the database rather than updating each and every value,

How good is this approach to optimize the application? , also I read on another site the following answer:

> - mySQL automatically detects that you're updating a field with the same value it already contains, and doesn't actually update that
>     field. Not sure if this is the same for other databases thet can be
>     used with php.

also, how true is the above statement?

Comment: it's true enough. mysql isn't going to waste time rewriting bytes on-disk if it doesn't have to. whether other databases have the same sort of optimization -- you'll have to check the documentation for those dbs.

Comment: @MarcB So you mean I should rely on mysql db optimizing itself instead of making my query optimized with PHP?

Comment: well, consider the extra workload you'd have to do: fetch the data to display in the form, get the form submitted, fetch the data AGAIN so you can compare the new against old values, then build a query which updates only the changed values. 2 selects + 1 update, v.s. 1 select + 1 update

Comment: Thankyou, it seems legit

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `$_POST` variables to construct your SQL query, just make sure you aren't including any column names or values that aren't set in `$_POST`.  If a SQL `UPDATE` statement doesn't have a value for a column and isn't formed to expect one, then the DB won't try to update those columns.  The best way is probably to use a `foreach` loop:

```
// Init SQL query
$statement = "UPDATE tableName SET ";
$params = array();
// Iterate $_POST variables
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    // Append a new SET key/value pair
    $statement .= "$key = :$key, ";
    // You're using prepared statements, right?
    $params[$key] = $value;
}

// Cut off last comma and append WHERE clause
$statement = substr($statement,0,-2)." WHERE id = :id";
// Store id for prepared statement
$params['id'] = $id;
// Prepare the query
$pdo->prepare($statement);
// Execute with parameters
$result = $pdo->execute($params);
```

Comment: It's dangerous to add $_POST directly into query without checking and escaping string. suppose `$_POST['age'] = "abcd"; // abcd is entered by user.` How this will be inserted into database?

Comment: That would result in
    "UPDATE tableName SET age='abcd' WHERE id = $id"

I did edit to make sure the ID was escaped for the prepared statement.  I went ahead and added a mock DB call while I was at it...

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple, after submitting the form, do:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
// Do the update
}
else {
// Don't do anything because it means there is no $_POST['name']
}
```

This is the basic logic, I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This would also work, with the disadvantage that you'd have to type out an `if` for each of your 16-20 fields and very tightly couple your script to your form.

Comment: There is not much detail from the OP what the actual form looks like, but just checking the variable is set or not won't help. It will always be set, even if it has not changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way of doing it is first call a fetch query and using a while loop populate the input fields as
<input type="text" name="name" value= 
now it will contain the previous value until user changes it in input filed like if he lefts it unchanged then previous value would be saved automaticaly